# For which $n$ is the symmetric group $S_n$ a subgroup of the special orthogonal group $SO(3)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

For which $n$ is the symmetric group $S_n$ a subgroup of the special orthogonal group $SO(3)$? For example, this holds for $n≤4$, however I don't know if it holds for $n=5$ or what happens for larger $n$.

Comment: It would be a faithful $3$-dimensional representation which [doesn't exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group) for $n\ge 5$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question can be attacked either as a question about the finite subgroups of $SO(3)$ or as a question about the representation theory of $S_n$. Each of these approaches will prove that $S_n \hookrightarrow SO(3)$ iff $n \le 4$.

**Finite subgroups:** It's a [classical result](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_subgroups_of_SO(3,R)) that the complete list of finite subgroups of $SO(3)$ is the following:

- the cyclic groups $C_n$,
- the dihedral groups $D_n$,
- the [tetrahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_symmetry) $A_4$,
- the [octahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedral_symmetry) $S_4$, or
- the [icosahedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry) $A_5$.

$S_4$ appears on this list but $S_n$ does not for $n \ge 5$.

**Representation theory:** The symmetric group $S_n$ [is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_symmetric_group) to have the property  that the lowest-dimensional faithful representation has dimension $n-1$ for $n \ge 5$, as reuns points out in the comments.